# C++, number length

Tags: c++, string, integer

How do I measure the length of numbers in c++? Have i tried using the function `len()`, but unsuccessfully, I think I need to translate int somehow in str, but then how to do it accordingly?

Comment: How do you define "the length of a number"? What is the length of the number 42, say?

Comment: Guesses and trials do not work in studying. Invest some time for reading one of the good books of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Some of them can be found on the Internet.

Comment: ***Have i tried using the function len()*** Numbers don't have any functions.

Comment: You could count the iterations of dividing by 10, until the number is zero.

Comment: Either ```int len( int N ){ return to_string( N ).length(); }``` or, without std::string, ```int len( int N ){ return N < 0 ? 1 + len( -N ) : N < 10 ? 1 : 1 + len( N / 10 ); }```

Comment: @Andrey Dorofeev, you need to explain what exactly you mean by the "length" of a number. Some guesses might include: the number of characters in its decimal representation; the number of characters in any other representation; the number of bytes to hold it; etc. Supply some desired input and output to explain this. Then upload the code that you have tried.

Comment: Oook,that sounds like mistranslation. Is that "length of string represenation of a number?"

Comment: Sigh. `int len = (int)log10(value)+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ there is no "len()" function only length(), for example if you're declaring a number as a string you can watch its length with the "variableName.length()" function

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string variable = "12345";
cout << variable.length();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int num;
   cout<<"Enter number: ";
   cin>>num;

   // Convert the integer to a string
   string strNumber = to_string(num);

   // Find the length of the string
   int length = strNumber.length();

   // Output the result
   cout << "Length: " << length << endl;

   return 0;
}
```